# Get Cookies from ServletRequest

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, cookies, servlet-listeners

I'm using `ServletRequestListener` to attach to new requests, get a `ServletRequest` object and extract cookies from it.

I've noticed that only `HTTPServletRequest` has cookies but I haven't found a connection between those two objects.

Is it okay to use

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext().getRequest());
```

to retrieve the request while in a `RequestInitialized` method? (I do want to run on every request)

FYI - This is all done in a JSF 1.2 Application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not correct. The `FacesContext` isn't available in a [`ServletRequestListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequestListener.html) per se. The `getCurrentInstance()` might return `null`, leading to NPE's.

If you're running the webapp on a HTTP webserver (and thus not some Portlet webserver for example), you could just cast the `ServletRequest` to `HttpServletRequest`.

```
public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent event) {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) event.getServletRequest();
    // ...
}
```

---

Note that a more common practice is to use a [`Filter`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) for this since you can map this on a fixed URL pattern like `*.jsf` or even on specific servlets so that it runs only when the `FacesServlet` runs. You might for example want to skip cookie checks on static resources like CSS/JS/images.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    // ...
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```

---

When you happens to be already inside the JSF context (in a managed bean, phaselistener or whatever), you could just use [`ExternalContext#getRequestCookieMap()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestCookieMap%28%29) to get the cookies.

```
Map<String, Object> cookies = externalContext.getRequestCookieMap();
// ...
```

When running JSF on top of Servlet API, the map value is of type [`javax.servlet.http.Cookie`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html).

```
Cookie cookie = (Cookie) cookies.get("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. In Web scenarios, this will always be ok. If you want to be sure, you could do a check for the type first. (Good practice anyway):

```
if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest() instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
...
```

By the way: Why do you have to use `FacesContext`? From where are you calling this code?

Comment: I don't have to. Is there another way? I'm using it cuz i'm in a JSF application.

Comment: Sorry, I think, I overlooked that part. Do you mean Application as in `javax.faces.application.Application`? In that case, you do not have a choice.